# Can I use SELinux to add an extra layer of protection against 0-day VM escape exploits in KVM/QEMU?

Tags: security, virtual-machine, kvm, selinux

My host is Fedora, and I want to add an extra layer of protection against 0day KVM/QEMU exploits that execute code on the host. For example there have been CVEs where if we run a specially crafted malicious windows executable on the windows VM as admin, it would execute code on the host.

I analyze malware from time to time and need to execute unknown malwares so can't do anything about that, and I don't want to buy a separate computer for that either.

My question is, can I leverage SELinux to protect myself against such exploits? Or does KVM/QEMU already use SELinux to protect against such attacks? Or is there a better approach to protect against these attacks?

EDIT:

The following is output of `semanage boolean -l | grep virt` In my updated Fedora 39 :

```
virt_lockd_blk_devs            (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to lockd blk devs
virt_qemu_ga_manage_ssh        (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to qemu ga manage ssh
virt_qemu_ga_read_nonsecurity_files (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to qemu ga read nonsecurity files
virt_qemu_ga_run_unconfined    (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to qemu ga run unconfined
virt_read_qemu_ga_data         (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to read qemu ga data
virt_rw_qemu_ga_data           (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to rw qemu ga data
virt_sandbox_share_apache_content (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to sandbox share apache content
virt_sandbox_use_all_caps      (on   ,   on)  Allow virt to sandbox use all caps
virt_sandbox_use_audit         (on   ,   on)  Allow virt to sandbox use audit
virt_sandbox_use_fusefs        (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to sandbox use fusefs
virt_sandbox_use_mknod         (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to sandbox use mknod
virt_sandbox_use_netlink       (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to sandbox use netlink
virt_sandbox_use_sys_admin     (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to sandbox use sys admin
virt_transition_userdomain     (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to transition userdomain
virt_use_comm                  (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use comm
virt_use_execmem               (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use execmem
virt_use_fusefs                (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use fusefs
virt_use_glusterd              (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use glusterd
virt_use_nfs                   (on   ,   on)  Allow virt to use nfs
virt_use_pcscd                 (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use pcscd
virt_use_rawip                 (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use rawip
virt_use_samba                 (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use samba
virt_use_sanlock               (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use sanlock
virt_use_usb                   (on   ,   on)  Allow virt to use usb
virt_use_xserver               (off  ,  off)  Allow virt to use xserver
```

Can someone explain which of these do I need to turn on or off to add extra protection against KVM/QEMU exploits without making the Windows VM unusable? My basic usage of the Windows VMs is that I code in some of them, and I run malware in others for analysis, and I don't need Internet connection for VMs, are these rules configured properly for this case or I can make it more secure?

Basically, If you were tasked with securing KVM/QEMU by using SELinux rules, which SELinux rules would you turn off or on to make it more secure?

There are literally 0 info on some of the above rules on the internet, for example what the hell does "`Allow virt to rw qemu ga data`" even mean? Ga Data??

Answer (score 3):

> My host is Fedora, and I want to add an extra layer of protection against 0day KVM/QEMU exploits that execute code on the host.

wow! These are *rare*. In any case, the nature of 0days is that you can't know the mechanism before hand. So, the only actual course of action is to either a) not use functionality or b) keep your functionality up with the releases.

> My question is, can I leverage SELinux to protect myself against such exploits?

Depends! The qemu executable runs in an SELinux context, and hence can only do what you allow it to do.

But if the 0day affects the KVM, kernel, side of things, there's no security boundaries there.

> Or is there a better approach to protect against these attacks?

Honestly, unless you're likely to be analyzing things that state-budget sized experts leverage against high-value targets, I'd recommend dialing down the worries, and just use the most up to date release of Linux.  Linux releases regularly exactly because that allows them to regularly ship patches to functionality that might or has been exploited.

If you're likely to be analyzing things that state-budget sized expert groups leverage against high-value targets (say, the whole of AWS, or the NSA,…), then why are you not working on a dedicated computer in an air-gapped network?

Comment: It's not THAT rare, there are POCs available for sale on some onion forums for exploits in VMware workstation and KVM for escaping VM, an attacker would just need to copy paste some codes after buying it. But back to the question, so there is nothing that I can do using SELinux to put a extra layer of protection?

Comment: What I wrote in the answer about SELinux is correct. It applies to userland processes. not to kernel functionality.

Comment: And if KVM escapes weren't rare, there'd be no cloud providers using that, so honestly, I do think you're overestimating danger there. If you are *not*, in your context, then why are we even talking about avoiding separate computers? You need to choose between being a little paranoid and being a little cheap.

Comment: I'm sure that these cloud providers are indeed putting extra protection in place, and don't place all their hope in that KVM doesn't have exploits..

Comment: For example what about this? https://selinuxproject.org/page/SVirt

Comment: @OneAndOnly it's nice what you believe. Let's stick to what the Linux kernel security people are saying (and guess who are the employers of these people? Right, it's GCP, AWS and Azure folks…): Keep your kernel up to date with the latest release, it doesn't get much more secure.

Comment: Re: SVirt: check slide 31 of the presentation on that wiki page from 2009 (!); it's a userland process mitigation. I mean, that's what SELinux (and other Mandatory Access Control plugins on linux) do: control what processes can do. No more, no less.

Comment: I understand that if there was a kernel mode exploit in KVM, that would be game over for us and we can't protect against it, but doesn't KVM/QEMU and their corresponding VMs have a usermode process as well? Then maybe an exploit would lead to code execution in these processes instead of kernelmode code execution. In this case, can't we at least protect these usermode processes? I understand that we can't protect against kernelmode exploits but at least we can protect from the usermode exploits, right?

Comment: I already addressed that in my answer. Yes, you can use SELinux against your QEMU/virtualizer host process. In fact, most linux distros will do that by the default SELinux rules they ship.

Comment: "most linux distros will do that by the default SELinux rules they ship" In my Updated fedora 39, I did a "sudo semanage boolean -l | grep virt", and many of these rules are turned off.  would you mind updating your answer and explain whether or not I need to turn on any of these that are off by default? Or is there any guide out there that explains which of these do I need to turn on for KVM/QEMU protection? I updated the question and Included the output for this command

Comment: I also Updated the question title, so people would understand I'm not asking to be protected against 100% of attacks, just want to use SELinux to add an extra layer of protection, that's it.

Comment: @OneAndOnly I can't tell you what layers of protection to enable for a vulnerability that neither of us knows yet, and which you have the distinct feeling will happen, but I don't believe that. You're the security expert here – it's your job to do the threat modelling.

Comment: Just assume that an exploit causes code execution in user-mode processes related to the VM such as qemu processes and we want to protect against it using SELinux.. Is that really that hard for you to grasp? Read https://qiuhao.org/Matryoshka_Trap.pdf  .And If I was an expert in configuring SELinux I wouldn't have been asking this question in the first place..

Comment: Using SELinux to force qemu related processes to only be able to access specific directories and be able to only create certain processes and not be able to Inject into another process would be a start..

Comment: I *can't* possibly know what **you** *want* the QEMU process to access and not access. How is that hard to understand? Please be reasonable

Comment: Yes, you can restrict file and trace access using SELinux. That's what it does; but you already knew that, I presume, when you asked the quesiton.